# Customers cant enter invoice address (SagePay Form)

Tags: forms, opayo

How can i get SagePay to allow my customers to enter an invoice address?

As i remember, when we changed to Forms v3 i was required to submit both addresses.  My site only collects the delivery address, so i send that through for both.  In the previous version, the customer landed at SagePay and could then enter their invoice address.  Now both addresses are prefilled and i just have + and - buttons to show/hide it.

How can i get back to SagePay collecting the invoice address?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just the cardholder address that was editable on the Default pages - not the delivery address.

If you want to return to the old templates, log in to My Sage Pay, click Settings, then Settings (again!) and then Edit your account settings, and set payment page templates to  default.

Comment: Sorry Rik, i meant my site collect the delivery address, and SagePay won't let the customer edit the invoice address. Don't want to go back to the old templates, but would like the customer to be able to edit the invoice address.  I'll edit my Q

Comment: I ended up updating my site to collect both addresses.  I'm marking this as the answer though, as the v3 SagePay templates just doesn't allow this, and switching back to the older templates is the only answer to my original question.